# pcolormesh plot with data from csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, heatmap

I have some time series data in the following format from csv file:

```
Time                  1     5     10   18   21   22   29   30   35
2019/11/01 09:00      5     0     8    1    2    36   7    6    9
2019/11/02 10:00      7     4     8    8    32   6    17   18   15
2019/11/03 11:00      1     4     8    12   8    9    4    22   11
2019/11/01 12:00      8     7     8    1    50   26   32   16   80
2019/11/02 13:00      6     1     11   5    102  26   11   8    19
```

The first column is time, 1-35 at the top is the monitoring site ID and the corresponding values are the PM2.5 concentrations.

I want to make a heatmap plot using pcolormesh, but I dont know how to put X, Y, Z in. X should be Time, Y is the monitoring site ID and Z is the values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A straightforward approach could use seaborn (`import seaborn as sns`). `sns.heatmap(data=df.set_index('Time'), annot=True)`

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use seaborn but it did not generate the plot I need.

Comment: It might help if you'd add the code an test data you tried, together with the resulting plot and an explanation how you need it to be different.